# I've been trying to use API for a stock site I've been making, my api has multiple words with space between them

Tags: json, api, object

With API's containing single word property "articles" can be accessed like `json.articles` and works well, whereas with property `Time Series (5min)` and accessing like `json.Time Series (5min)` wouldn't work. I tried including hyphens, removing the space, but it just wouldn't work.

I'm still new to all this and learning everyday, a little help would be appreciated. Thank you :)
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5KQq.png) and [api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yj3h6.png)

Comment: `let time = json['Time Series (5min)'];`

Comment: Thank you so much @navnath!! the former actually worked

Comment: consider accepting answer if was helpful.

Answer (score -1):

You can use array syntax to access such Object properties

```
let json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

let time = json['Time Series (5min)'];
```